# How wrong is my idea for calculating 2D coordinates from 3D space coordinates data

Tags: rendering, processing, perspective

I've been trying to write a program in Processing 3, which will display points from 3D space onto the viewport. I won't be showing any code for now because the point of this question is if there are any disadvantages in my method for displaying space in perspective.

[image: Relationships between vectors and points in relation to the camera's direction]

The idea behind my formula for calculating X and Y screen coordinates for a point in 3D space is to compare alpha and beta angles (angles on the picture, values don't matter right now).
Since the 0,0 coordinates on the screen starts in the upper-left corner, here's what I came up for X and Y:

[image]

[image]

where:

- γ is the angle between the right edge of the FOV and CP OR just α+β
- β is the Field of View half angle
- α is the angle between the camera's forward vector and CP vector.
- is the same as γ but on a XZ plane (looking up and down)

This way, when:

- α = 0, the X is width and that puts the point at the right edge of the screen
- α = β, the X is the middle of the screen (width/2), and
- α = 2β, the X is 0 and that's the left edge of the screen.

I did calculate angles using acos() and asin() functions and they were correct. 
The first problem was the α angle; it never was negative, meaning that γ would never go below β since

β+α = β+0.

I managed to fix it by multiplying α with a cross product of CP and direction (on the image) vectors to determine if α is positive or negative.

At first I though I fixed the problem but as soon as I rotated the camera, the point on the screen would go to the right only to a certain value and then bounce back in the opposite direction (as if the cross product didn't work anymore or something).

Do you have any idea if there are any downsides in my formulas?
Thanks for help!

Comment: I've now idea what you try to achieve. But I know very well how 3D objects are rendered in general. At 3D rendering [perspective projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection) is used. the coordinates are transformed by a 4x4 projection matrix and a final perspective divide. At Perspective Projection the projection matrix describes the mapping from 3D points in the world as they are seen from of a pinhole camera, to 2D points of the viewport.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It seems to be what I was trying to achieve in some way.
The point of my calculations at the top was to achieve perspective projection on XY plane only for any angle around z axis.

Comment: [Processing - P3D](https://processing.org/tutorials/p3d/) may be of interest, too - especially the chapter "Perspective"